# How can I enable the camera without using raspi-config?

Tags: raspicam, raspi-config

I am trying to use the raspi camera on a minimalized version of wheezy. The command `raspi-config` is not available. I have been able to do everything without it so far by editting `/boot/config.txt` or installing missing software with `apt-get`.

Unfortunately, everywhere I look, all tutorials on the camera (including the official RaspiCam-Documentation.pdf) say to first enable it with `raspi-config`. So, **what does raspi-config actually do to the Pi that I can reproduce manually?**

Comment: FYI Using start_x=1 in config.txt stops my xbian from booting and causes sd card corruption meaning a whole new image has to be flashed to the sd card.

Comment: Adding start_x=1 and gpu_mem=128 to the /boot/config.txt file on a Ubuntu 20.10 arm64 for Raspberry Pi 4 leads to an unfixable boot failure where it hangs on the splash screen indefinitely.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK. `raspi-config` is actually a bit of bash, so it's quite easy to see what it does:

```sh
# $1 is 0 to disable camera, 1 to enable it
set_camera() {
  # Stop if /boot is not a mountpoint
  if ! mountpoint -q /boot; then
    return 1
  fi

  [ -e /boot/config.txt ] || touch /boot/config.txt

  if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then # disable camera
    set_config_var start_x 0 /boot/config.txt
    sed /boot/config.txt -i -e "s/^startx/#startx/"
    sed /boot/config.txt -i -e "s/^start_file/#start_file/"
    sed /boot/config.txt -i -e "s/^fixup_file/#fixup_file/"
  else # enable camera
    set_config_var start_x 1 /boot/config.txt
    CUR_GPU_MEM=$(get_config_var gpu_mem /boot/config.txt)
    if [ -z "$CUR_GPU_MEM" ] || [ "$CUR_GPU_MEM" -lt 128 ]; then
      set_config_var gpu_mem 128 /boot/config.txt
    fi
    sed /boot/config.txt -i -e "s/^startx/#startx/"
    sed /boot/config.txt -i -e "s/^fixup_file/#fixup_file/"
  fi
}
```

Apparently there's an entry in /boot/config.txt called `start_x` that needs to be set to `1` to enable the camera, There also needs to be at least 128 MB of memory for the gpu (gpu_mem). [Double check seems to confirm it.](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=65696&p=495332)

Comment: [Here's the full source code](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config), in case anyone's interested. The function now seems to be called `do_camera`.

Answer (score 17):

edit your /boot/config.txt file and make sure the following lines look like this:

```
start_x=1             # essential
gpu_mem=128           # at least, or maybe more if you wish
disable_camera_led=1  # optional, if you don't want the led to glow
```

reboot

Answer (score 7):

What raspi-config does is changing the `/boot/config.txt`. There is a string inside that file which says `start_x=0` when camera is disabled. By changing that to `start_x=1` will enable the camera. You will have to reboot after you edited the file.

I made a script that searches the `/boot/config.txt` for the string "start_x=0" and if it finds it changes it to "start_x=1". Use the following code, and don't forget to chmod +x and run with sudo.

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "start_x=1" /boot/config.txt
if grep "start_x=1" /boot/config.txt
then
        exit
else
        sed -i "s/start_x=0/start_x=1/g" /boot/config.txt
        reboot
fi
exit
```

Comment: +1 What is the first grep for? And Is it possible that before the first startup there is no such line as `start_x=*` ?

Comment: The first grep might be useful for debugging purposes. It is not required for the script's operation. 

In my Raspbian stretch config.txt file I cannot find a `start_x` line in `config.txt`, so this script will not work as it is.

Answer (score 7):

`raspi-config` seems to support noninteractive mode: you can use `nonint` command to set the `camera`

```
# raspi-config nonint do_camera %d
# %d - Integer input - 0 is in general success / yes / selected, 1 is failed / no / not selected

sudo raspi-config nonint do_camera 0
```

For more details please check the full list of options:
https://github.com/l10n-tw/rc_gui/blob/master/src/rc_gui.c#L50-L100

Answer (score 0):

For the Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20, to enable v4l2 for CSI run

```
sudo nano /boot/firmware/config.txt
```

and add these lines:

```
gpu_mem=512
disable_camera_led=1
start_file=start4x.elf
fixup_file=fixup4x.dat
```

Comment: Not sure why but this doesn’t work on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.